# How do I display user picture from profile fields?

Tags: 7, privatemsg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I display a picture from a field as the user picture rather than the drupal default with user-picture.tpl.php?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-can-i-display-a-picture-from-a-field-as-the-user-picture-rather-than-the-dru)

I would like to display the user pictures in message list and message view. The images are uploaded through a user profile field, and not the default Drupal account picture field.

How do I do this in Drupal 7?

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-can-i-display-a-picture-from-a-field-as-the-user-picture-rather-than-the-dru

Answer (score 2):

Private Message displays the user picture via a theme('user_picture') so I'd just copy the `user-picture.tpl.php` template out of the system user module directory and into your theme's and modify it to display your field instead of the default.  You may want to put additional logic in there so that it doesn't do this everywhere but that's up to you.