# Change the default image based on certain condition

Tags: media

I wonder if I could provide two default images -one for boys & other for girls.

In the registration form they can choose their sex from a Boolean field.

Is it possible with conditional fields ? How?
I'm not  a programmer, so please make your answer detailed.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37511/how-can-i-assign-users-different-profile-pictures-upon-registration-based-on-gen might help you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) as follows:

You can either include [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) for a single Rule, or use two rules:

Event: After user registration

Condition: image field is empty (only want it to run if they don't upload an image)

Condition: sex field is girl

Action: set image field to url location of girl default image

New Rule:

same as above except for the condition of sex changes to boy

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Comment: Sorry........I just couldn't make it.

can you please say the exact condition & action to select?

So far, I've used this & couldn't find what action would let me put the default image url.


Event: After saving a new user account
Conditions: Data value is empty (Parameter: Data to check: [account:field-profile-pic]) 

& Data comparison (Parameter: Data to compare: [account:field-sex], Data value: Male) 

Action: Set a data value ?

Comment: that looks correct - how is it not working?  try to add an action to set a message (any message just for testing) - this will tell us if the problem is with the event and conditions or the action - could also start only with a message action and event, try it, then start adding conditions until it fails (if its a condition problem)

Comment: Showing a message is easy as there is a clear action for this. But, I don't see any appropriate action to divert the default image to a certain url. 

So far I can found 'set a Data value'   then, it ask for a 'data selector' where I can choose 'account:field-profile-pic' ,,, then it ask for  data value, but it forcing for the  same 'account:field-profile-pic' to select . There are no field where I can put the url. 

if you can-- please export the rules for me. my fields machine name: sex: field_sex ; image field: field_profile_pic

Comment: there should be a button to change the value to 'direct input' where you can type in a value rather than using a field

Comment: yup, I can swear I saw that before, but somehow now its been disappeared. I'll look for this, & will come back :)