# How to add user picture to created node?

Tags: 7, users, media

User image has to be added to created node.
So when user creates node user image has to automatically be added to it.
How it can be accomplished?

Comment: version of drupal?  is this just for display on a page or do you require each node to actually have an image file field with a user's image in it?

Comment: It's just for display. Drupal 7

Comment: In D6, you would go to `admin/build/themes/settings` and turn on `User Pictures in Posts` so I would imagine there is a similar option in D7.

Comment: It is and it's enabled by default but it doesn't show any images. And I have to show not default user avatar but custom image field called user_signature.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-can-i-display-a-picture-from-a-field-as-the-user-picture-rather-than-the-dru talks to using a different field for a user's picture and might be of help

Comment: Did you enable user pictures on admin/config/people/accounts?

Comment: Yes it's enabled on admin/config/people/accounts  and enabled in theme settings(global and in default theme settings). Default theme - bartik.